# How to set class weights for tensorflow model in multiple labels question?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

I try to train a model to predict several labels by image. The output is a list contained five binary values, like this [0,0,0,1,1]

I use a sigmoid dense layer to get the output, and here is my code:

```
inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (*IMAGE_SIZE, 3), name = 'inp')
x = tfka.ResNet50(weights = 'imagenet', include_top = False)(inp)
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(label_dim, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = [inp], outputs = [output])
```

Now, my problem is that my dataset is unbalanced. And it is difficult to make it balanced because each row has five labels. So, I try to set different class weights for each label but I don't know how to do it.

I try

```
class_weight = {'label-1': 1:2, 'label-2': 1:5, 'label-3': 1:1, 'label-4': 2:1, 'label-5': 1:10}
```

But it doesn't work.

My target is to assign different weights for all classes and labels. like this

In the first label, the weight of class 0 is 0.5, and the weight of 1 is 1

In the second label, the weight of class 0 is 0.1, and the weight of 1 is 1

...

UPDATE:

I think I should split my model into five tiny models because what I want is to minimize the loss for each label rather than the label list. So converting it to be several single binary classification models is a better choice.

Comment: In Python, `m:n` is not a ratio. Try using floats for your weights, like 1:2 becomes 0.5, 1:5 becomes 0.2, 2:1 becomes 2.0, etc.

Comment: If you look at the tensorflow documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit), you can see that the .fit() can take a class_weight parameter.

Comment: But, the .fit() weight is for class not for label. If I just have one label with 3 classes, it works like {'A':0.5, 'B':1, 'C':2}. But now I have 5 labels and each one has two classes. So. it is so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the weights for each class when fitting the model. The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) from Tensorflow specifies that when called .fit(), you can pass a dictionary containing the class weights. Make sure to check how this dictionary should look like, since it only accepts a integer (key) and float (weight) format.

Comment: Yes, now I understand my error about the weight set, but I want to know how to mark them. like {0:0.5} for label 1 and {0:2} for label2, ...... I think splitting my model and just predicting one label is a possible solution. But it seems time-consuming and too much repetitive work. Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using images as input, maybe you can try using ImageDataGenerator and then use .flow_from_dataframe() in order to know the indices where each label is located at. When you say you want to know how to mark them, do you mean how to compute the weight for each label?@Carlos

Comment: Yes. I have checked the loss function, and I think I should split my model into several tiny models. Briefly, I want to get the least loss for each label. But my output combinates all label values, so when calculating loss, other values may impact the result.